# Determine function from Reimann sum

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

> Determine which of the following is equal to
> $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{34}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{34^2i^2}{n^2} + 1 \right)
> $$
> (Answer: the area of the region above the $x$-axis below $f(x)=(x-1)^2+1$, from $x=1$ to $x=35$.)

I got a correct answer only because I knew the final $x$ and the initial $x$ have to have a difference of $34$. I have no idea how this function came about though and I would like some help

Comment: Are you familiar with Riemann sums?

Comment: @Gary Some basics, yes. I have learned them only a while back and I haven't encountered such questions yet.

Comment: Try to write down a Riemann sum for $x^2  - 1$ on $(0,34)$ with steps $\frac{34}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the sum suggests you are adding $n$ rectangles of width $34/n$ and different heights given by the sum. The common width, as you mention, suggests that you have $n$ rectangles over an interval of width $34$, which we can represent as $(a,a+34)$.

As for the heights, the height of rectangle $i$, over the interval $\left( a+\frac{34(i-1)}{n}, a+\frac{34i}{n}\right)$ is given by the $i$-th term of the sum, namely $\frac{34^2i^2}{n^2}+1$, which sounds a lot like one of those endpoints plugged into the function $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Can you now finish?

---

**UPDATE**

Imagine writing down a Riemann sum of $n$ rectangles for $\int_a^{a+L} \left(x^2+1\right) dx$. The width of one rectangle is $L/n$, and the $i$-th interval is $(a + (i-1)L/n, a+iL/n)$, so if you are using the RHS endpoint the height will be $(a+iL/n)^2+1$ and if you want the LHS endpoint, you get $(a + (i-1)L/n)+1$.

So the total sum for your integral becomes
$$
\int_a^{a+L} \left(x^2+1\right)dx
 = \lim_{n \to \infty}
   \frac{L}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\left(a+\frac{iL}{n}\right)^2+1\right]
$$

Comment: Honestly I'm still confused. What do you mean by "which sounds a lot like one of those endpoints plugged into the function $f(x)=x^2+1$"? @gt6989b

Comment: @user737163 please see another related example in the update

Comment: I now understand what you wrote, thanks. I just don't see how this relates to my question and how I can solve it using this knowledge

Comment: @user737163 you can recognize your sum as this one with $a=0$ for example. Your expression is very similar since you are using a translated $f(x) = (x-1)^2+1$...